# How should I fix my Ortlieb Rack Pack (medium, 31 litres) to my rear panniers?

Tags: panniers, bags

I recently bought an Ortlieb Rack Pack to go across the top of my rear pannier rack. When the pannier bags are attached the Rack Pack works great: it clips into the two pannier bags and everything holds together nicely.

[image]

However, if I'm only using one pannier bag or if I'm using the Rack Pack on its own, I struggle to get the Rack Pack secured to the rear pannier rack. I'm thinking of using a bungee cord, but should I try something else instead? Is there a different kind of strap that is specifically designed for fixing things to panniers?

Comment: Why not just use the rack pack last?

Comment: Could point! I used to use two pannier bags, one containing my work stuff and another containing my stuff for the gym. I found that the narrow opening of a pannier bag didn't work too well for gym stuff, so I went for the rack pack instead :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with a couple of bungee cords, maybe the adjustable-length ones.  That's probably going to be more versatile and adaptable than something more specialized.

There are some flat adjustable bungees, like these:
[image]

[http://www.amazon.com/ROK-Straps-Adjustable-Loop-Thru-BLACK/dp/B008ETMV8I](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008ETMV8I)

That particular type is attached on either side such that you can open it without having the entire strap coming off the bike. Both ends are a plain nylon strap, and the middle section is stretchy.  I've used these for motorcycle luggage and I liked them.

Comment: Thank you, this is precisely what I was looking for -- I think I may have seen someone mention ROK straps online before. I'm in the UK so ROK straps can be tricky to find, so just in case anyone else stumbles across this answer in the future, here's one UK supplier I've found: http://www.motorcycle-road-and-race.co.uk/rok-straps-adjustable-12-42-inch-pair-?gclid=CjwKEAjw0-epBRDOp7f7lOG0zl4SJABxJg9qibeHecy8PyGhXfdHnLZw5tv26jAIONYbsqffYhEUeBoC2sfw_wcB

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same setup:

[image]

On the end of the bag, I clipped it to the panniers using the built-in clips, as you're doing, but I would *not* trust this to keep the bag stationary.

I just bought one of those big containers of bungee cords of different lengths from Canadian Tire, and used the two shortest ones to go around the bag's middle. It looks like I actually missed the handle there, but usually I run them through the handles so they can't slip off.

They work well without the panniers, provided you run the bungies through the handles.

Dirt cheap, and kept it in place really well.

Answer (score -1):

I bought some ROK straps from Cycleblaze.  There are two sizes.  You thread one end of each strap through the loop at the end of the strap, then buckle them together.  I got the small, but I would advise the large.

Comment: Welcome to the site, don’t forget to take the [tour]. Can you elaborate on why these work so well and if you’ve been using them to do the same kind of task as the question? It would be useful to know what makes these work so well in case people can’t find the same thing where they are, or in the future.